# Lipstchitzian function : $|g'(t)| < \lambda$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuos and of class $\mathbb{C}^1$. If $|g'(x)| < \lambda < 1$, it is possible to say that $|g(x) - g(x_o)| < \lambda |x-x_o|?$

I am not sure if the continuity of $g$ permits me to affirm that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Lipschitzian function", or more commonly, "Lipschitz function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

By Mean Value Theorem in $[x_0,x]$ we get ${g(x)-g(x_0)\over x_0-x}=g'(c)<\lambda$ for some $c\in(x_0,x)$